# PHP Fatal error: Allowed memory exausted

Tags: php-errors

i ran into an HTTP Error 500(internal server error) when i tried to edit one of my page. it was working fine up until last week. i tried to to increased the Memory limit in to 256M, didn't help.

my error log says this: "PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 268435456 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 43504 bytes) in *path/to/my/websit"/system/extensions/fieldtypes/ngen_file_field/ft.ngen_file_field.php on line 1074"

Comment: I ran into the same error last week, and my ISP cannot seem to fix it. I get a virtual memory spike whenever I am uploading to my website, which brings down the website. Depending on what I am trying to do, I get "Fatal error: Out of memory..." Today, when I was trying to upload a pdf (4 Mb), I got "The uploaded file exceeds the maximum allowed size in your PHP configuration file." That's a new one. We upload PDFs to the site all of the time that are larger than that. The problem started, though, when I was editing text in a static page. My ISP has not been able to solve this issue in a week.

Comment: This should be asked as a new question. Also it would help to include a more exact description of what you're doing in eecms when you get the error.

Answer (score 1):

Usually this happens when a large image has been uploaded and ngen_file_field attempts to resize it and promptly runs out of memory.

This can be a particular problem with high DPI images - 300DPi print images are usually a culprit or simply very large over-sized images 2000+ pixels wide for example.

Take a look at recent images uploaded via FTP and see if you can spot any large images, download them and scale them appropriately before re-uploading them and it should clear the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Increasing your PHP memory should be a last resort and is pretty much NEVER advisable. Judging from your error it looks like an upload FT is using really poor practices for handling the files you're managing (there is rarely a reason to open an entire file into PHPs memory like that).

Were it me, I'd look into either moving away from that specific add-on to something that handles files with a little more care or creating a special case for that specific entry/file.

That said, 256MB of memory is just insane. Really, that's a lot of memory to allow PHP to use so you may see some really negative side effects.

Answer (score -1):

It looks like it needs more then 256M did you try to increase it to 512M? Be aware that not all servers allow htaccess to increase the memory limit.

```
php_value memory_limit 512M
```

Comment: Holy hell;  no, no, noooooo. If a site needs that much memory something is insanely wrong and should be looked into.